# Task showing different updates when having same due date

Tags: lightning, tasks, task-notifications

I am creating two task one from Account object and another from a custom object, both are related, when creating task from Account it show different update but when created from custom object it shows different one. as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: One is logged as a call and other is a task. What are you putting in the Subject for both?

Comment: I am creating it same as task but it shows two different updates both records are identical.

Comment: What are you putting in as a Subject for both?